# CSRF: Yesod runFormPost always FormFailure

Tags: haskell, csrf, yesod

Apologies in advance for the code dump. I'm pretty new to both Yesod and Haskell and I'm struggling with CSRF issues. The problem as I understand it is that the form's `_token` isn't matching the environment token (running runFormPostNoToken works just fine). I have a pair of routes:

```
/           HomeR      GET
/upload     UploadR    POST
```

The Handler for HomeR is defined as such:

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = do
    ((res, uploadWidget), enctype) <- runFormPost imgForm
    setTitle "Title"
    $(widgetFile "homepage")
```

And the form itself and the upload Handler are:

```
imgForm :: Html -> MForm (HandlerT App IO) (FormResult Img, Widget) 
imgForm hiddenInput = do
    (titleRes, titleView)   <- mreq textField uploadFormTitleSettings Nothing
    (descRes, descView)     <- mopt textareaField uploadFormDescriptionSettings Nothing
    (fileRes, fileView)     <- mreq fileField uploadFormAttachmentSettings Nothing

    let imgRes =  Img
              <$> titleRes
              <*> descRes
              <*> fileRes
              <*> pure (Likes 0)
              <*> pure (Dislikes 0) 
              <*> pure (UserID 1) 
              <*> pure (Community 1) 

    let imgUploadWidget = do
                      toWidget
                          [whamlet|
                              ^{ fvInput titleView }
                              ^{ fvInput descView }
                              ^{ fvInput fileView }
                              #{ hiddenInput }
                              <button type="submit">Submit
                          |]

    return (imgRes, imgUploadWidget)

postImgUploadR :: HandlerT App IO Html
postImgUploadR = do
    ((imgRes, imgUploadWidget), enctype) <- runFormPost imgForm
    let submission :: HandlerT App IO Html
        submission = case imgRes of
            FormSuccess upload -> defaultLayout [whamlet|The form was uploaded|]
            FormMissing -> defaultLayout [whamlet|The form is missing|]
            FormFailure upload -> defaultLayout [whamlet|The form failed.|]
    submission
```

Unfortunately I'm not even sure what question to be asking here -- hopefully there's something obviously wrong with my code and someone can point me in the right direction. I spent some time reading through the source code of the functions and I *think* I understand it, but I'm not sure where the second, erroneous CSRF token is coming from (I assumed it would be set in a session variable and therefore wouldn't change). It's been quite a few hours and all my attempts to figure this out have failed.

Comment: Have you tried using `generateFormPost` in your GET request and `runFormPost` in your POST handler?

Comment: @creichert I have not. I'll give it a shot ASAP...if it's that simple I'm gonna be kicking myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this turns out to be one of the most time-consuming bugs with one of the most mundane answers I've ever dealt with.

Some time ago I added in `sslOnlySessions` to `makeSessionBackend` and forgot about it. After trying to wrap my brain around every possible way I could have done something wrong, I took a step back, tried to think of a different angle to approach the problem from, and it hit me like a ton of bricks.

I'm posting this answer on the off chance someone 10 years from now will make the same dumb mistake I did, and after scouring their code for mistakes, finally fire up Google and find an easy answer.

Godspeed, future Haskeller.